# CSS - Render 10% of the image below the viewport for all screen sizes

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a mobile layout for the website I am building, where the image of a mobile screen has to always appear a till it's navigation buttons. Below is the design mockup of how the image should look

[image]

I am using media queries, the width of the image and margin-top to position it according to the mockup. But at certain viewports, the image appears completely above the screen, which is mostly due to the different viewports resulting in different values for the percentage based units I am using.
An example image of what I am trying to convey:

[image]

Is there a better approach to position this image, so that it always shows up to its navigation bar, so that the position is consistent atleast in a particular viewport range, if not every viewport?

Any help is appreciated.

the website for reference : https://hackertronix.com

```css
.mobile-phone-img {
  display: block;
  margin: 3% auto 0;
  width: 70%;
}

@media screen and (min-width:24em) {
  .mobile-phone-img {
    margin: 2.5% auto 0;
    width: 85%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:25.75em) {
  .mobile-phone-img {
    margin: 11.5% auto 0;
    width: 66%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:30em) {
  .mobile-phone-img {
    margin: 11.5% auto 0;
    width: 60%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:37.5em) {
  .mobile-phone-img {
    margin: 2.5% auto 0;
    width: 65%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:42em) {
  .mobile-phone-img {
    margin: 2.5% auto 0;
    width: 55%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:48em) {
  .mobile-phone-img {
    margin: 2.5% auto 0;
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:50em) {
  .mobile-phone-img {
    margin: 2.5% auto 0;
    width: 45%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:55em) {
  .mobile-phone-img {
    margin: 2.5% auto 0;
    width: 40%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-card">
  <h2>
    Tracker
  </h2>
  <a target="_blank" href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tracker.gst.in.gsttracker">
    <img src="images/getOnGooglePlay.png" class="mobile-button">
  </a>
  <img src="images/gst-tracker-pixel.png" class="mobile-phone-img">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well known media query resolution for almost every devices.

```
 /* 
      ##Device = Desktops
      ##Screen = 1281px to higher resolution desktops
    */

    @media (min-width: 1281px) {

      //CSS

    }

    /* 
      ##Device = Laptops, Desktops
      ##Screen = B/w 1025px to 1280px
    */

    @media (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1280px) {

      //CSS

    }

    /* 
      ##Device = Tablets, Ipads (portrait)
      ##Screen = B/w 768px to 1024px
    */

    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {

      //CSS

    }

    /* 
      ##Device = Tablets, Ipads (landscape)
      ##Screen = B/w 768px to 1024px
    */

    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {

      //CSS

    }

    /* 
      ##Device = Low Resolution Tablets, Mobiles (Landscape)
      ##Screen = B/w 481px to 767px
    */

    @media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {

      //CSS

    }

    /* 
      ##Device = Most of the Smartphones Mobiles (Portrait)
      ##Screen = B/w 320px to 479px
    */

    @media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {

      //CSS

    }
```

Comment: the !important isn'ta ctually present in the actual code, it made itself to the source file because of a faulty commit. my values are `margin: 30% auto` and `width: 70%`.

Comment: I have written media queries to position the photo according to the mockup, but the approach I follow doesn't work for every device, even though it lies within the range of media queries I have written. So I am asking if there is a better pproach to do it, in lesser code.

Comment: Well, what device did you aim? what is the resolution? Did you use any frameworks/library to support mobile-friendly? There are no better approach than @media screen .

Comment: At present I am trying to target most devices. I know it's difficult to make it look pixel perfect on every device, but let's say as of now the most popular ones. Iphones, Samsung devices etc. I have a oneplus so I know it works perfectly on that.